# Small question concerning equality of sets

Tags: measure-theory

I have this lemma :

> Let $(T,\mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space , If $\mathcal{A}$ is
>   generated by the familly $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ then for every $t$ $$
>  \displaystyle\bigcap_{i} \lbrace\theta\in T;
>  \chi_{A_i}(\theta)=\chi_{A_i}(t)\rbrace=\bigcap_{A \in
>  \mathcal{A}}\lbrace\theta\in
>  T;\chi_A(\theta)=\chi_A(t)\rbrace=\bigcap\lbrace A; t\in A \,and \,A
>  \in \mathcal{A}\rbrace$$ 
>   ...

For the first equality i done it easely ​​but for the second it seems easy, but I don't know how to write the solution  !

Hetp me please,

Thank you .

Comment: If all you are having problems with is writing up your solution, perhaps include an attempt at writing it up for users here to critique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second equality. So $t$ is fixed. Note that $\theta$ belong to the lhs means: for every $A\in \mathcal A$, $\chi_A(\theta)=\chi_A(t)$. This is an alternative: $\theta \in A$ if $t\in A$ or $\theta\in A^c=T\setminus A$ if $t\in A^c$. In other words, the lhs is equal to
$$
\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal A,\;t\in A} A\;\cup\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal A,\;t\not\in A} A^c.
$$
Now observe that these two sets are actually the same, both equal to the rhs of the equality.

You could also write directly that your lhs is equal to
$$
\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal A,\;t\in A} \{\theta\;;\;\chi_A(\theta)=1\}\;\cup\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal A,\;t\not\in A}  \{\theta\;;\;\chi_A(\theta)=0\}.
$$
Then you get the formula above as $\{\theta\;;\;\chi_A(\theta)=1\}$ is $A$ and $\{\theta\;;\;\chi_A(\theta)=0\}$ is $A^c$.